# How can I set a background image to the entire page of my site?

Tags: html, css, background-image

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/hfhfp/

For example, I'd like the user to scroll down, but the image to **not** move.

Any suggestions to my CSS?

Similar to http://www.mobafire.com/ where the picture is set, but the scrolling doesn't move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign backgroun-attachment property to fixed for body element.
i.e:

```
body{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C5Ym.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Check jsFiddle@: http://jsfiddle.net/hfhfp/2/

Answer (score 3):

Add fixed to the background properties like so :

```
body{
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C5Ym.jpg') fixed no-repeat;
}
```